# Populate javascript gallery from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, image

I have the following gallery -

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="myGallery">
        <div class="imageElement">
            <h3>IMAGE 1</h3>
            <p></p>
            <a href="#" title="open image" class="open"></a>
            <img src="image1.jpg" class="full" />
            <img src="image.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="imageElement">
            <h3>IMAGE 2</h3>
            <p></p>
            <a href="#" title="open image" class="open"></a>
            <img src="image2.jpg" class="full" />
            <img src="image2.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine when the images are hard coded like above, getting read from a folder.

However I wish to populate the gallery from the code behind with images I do not have stored but from a URL. Like - `www.fooBar.com/image1.png` and once this is retrieved then push it into the gallery?

I have tried the following -

Setting `<div id="myGallery" id="testHtml">`

then in the code behind -

```
testHtml.innerHTML = // built html with image src = url etc
```

However this just rendered the image without putting it into the gallery itself.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: are you using asp.net web forms?

Comment: @Dmytro Tsiniavskyi added what I have tried and I am using asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No shortage of ways to skin this cat, but one way is to create a literal like this:

```
 <div id="myGallery">
    <asp:Literal id="ltrImages" runat="server" />
 </div>
```

Then in your codebehind:

```
 var imageElement @"<div class=""imageElement"">
        <h3>{0}</h3>
        <p></p>
        <a href=""#"" title=""open image"" class=""open""></a>
        <img src=""{1}"" class=""full"" />
        <img src=""{1}"" class=""thumbnail"" />
    </div>";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 //Presuming you have your images in some kind of collection called "images"
 for(var image in images){
      sb.Append(String.Format(imageElement, image.title, image.src));
 }

 ltrImages.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:Panel>` has a property named `Controls` which you could use in order to add your `<div class="imageElement">` containers, images, headers and more.

See here for how to add an item: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.110).aspx

See here how to create a custom tag: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f8y80ez(v=vs.110).aspx